# How to trigger Jenkins downstream build job with a delay?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

From the `test-upstream` Pipeline job, I call `test-downstream` as below:

```
build job: "test-downstream", parameters: [[$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'computer', label: env.NODE_NAME]]
```

it works, but is there a way to delay the start, or schedule it to run 30 minutes later?

Looking for something like:

```
build job: "test-downstream", delayStart: 30m, parameters: [[$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'computer', label: env.NODE_NAME]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`quietPeriod: <number in seconds>` is the parameter I was looking for, it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
quietPeriod (optional)
Optional alternate quiet period (in seconds) before building. If unset, defaults to the quiet period defined by the downstream project (or finally to the system-wide default quiet period).
```

Reference -
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/